# With a roar from the crowd to speed them upwards

Tags: grammar

> **With a roar from the crowd to speed them upwards**, the fourteen players
> rose towards the leaden sky. Harry flew higher than any of them,
> squinting around for the Snitch.

From Harry Potter

Can I change the text in bold into "**with it to speed them upwards**" if "a roar from the crowd" can be easily understood? I'm analysing the syntax, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I don't think you could. "with it to speed them upwards" wouldn't make any sense here. I think the way to understand it is to swap the two parts of the first sentence: "The fourteen players rose towards the leaden sky with a roar from the crowd to speed them upwards." It's reversed for dramatic effect.

Comment: @JacobPeattie What I wonder is: is "a roar from the crowd to speed them upwards" a whole prepositional phrase, isn't it? Then, what is "to" connected to? For example "pretty guy", "pretty" is connected to "guy" without guy "pretty" can't stand alone. What is "to" for?

Comment: It's like saying "with a map to guide them". You could say "They set out with a map to guide them.", but you could also say "With a map to guide them, they set out.". You can start a sentence with a prepositional phrase. The "to" is attached to "speed them upwards", meaning that the roar from the crowd is speeding them upwards. A roar from a crowd can't literally speed somebody upwards, so it's metaphorical language.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I mean is "a roar from the crowd to speed them upwards" a whole noun phrase?

Comment: Why don't you just ask, what is the grammatical structure and role of "with a roar from the crowd to speed them upwards", rather than making up questions that you hope will take you part-way to an answer?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be revealing some unwritten rules about the usage of "it".

If we imagine the pronoun "it" can be substituted for any noun or noun phrase that was already known, then "a roar", or "a roar from the crowd" should be replaceable  by "it" and everything would be fine.  However that doesn't look correct here.

"it" is only appropriate in certain circumstances.

- it's very clearly understood what "it" is referring to
- often, the noun is a basic object
- repeating the same word, again and again, is repetitive. We'd like to avoid that, so instead of renaming the object, we alternately say "it".

Your example violates all of those premises.

- It's unlikely "a roar from the crowd" is being repeated. It only appears once. Therefore it doesn't need to be substituted.
- It's unlikely that "a roar from the crowd" is clearly in the reader's mind, to such an extent that when you say "it", they immediately think back to "roar" and know what it's referring to.
- This is literary, descriptive, metaphorical language which is the opposite of a language shortcut where you quickly refer to a "thing" as "it".